# Room Type Convertor causing values not to be saved

Tags: kotlin, android-room, typeconverter

When I use a typeconvertor in room for either nested data classes or lists/arraylists ,no values arent saved but when i use the exact code without any field that requires typeconvertors, values are saved in DB (which i can view with App Inspection)

```kotlin
@Entity
data class User(
    @PrimaryKey val uid: Int,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "first_name") val firstName: String?,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "last_name") val lastName: String?,

    //Nested Data Class cause of values not being saved
    @ColumnInfo(name = "WOW") val wow:Wow
)
data class Wow(val a: String,val b:String)

@Dao
interface UserDao {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM user")
    fun getAll():LiveData<List<User>>

    @Query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE uid IN (:userIds)")
    fun loadAllByIds(userIds: IntArray): List<User>

    @Query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE first_name LIKE :first AND last_name LIKE :last LIMIT 1")
    fun findByName(first: String, last: String): User

    @Insert
    fun insertAll(vararg users: User)

    @Delete
    fun delete(user: User)
}
class TypeConverterWOW(){
    @TypeConverter
    fun listToJson(value:Wow) = Json.encodeToString(value)
    @TypeConverter
    fun jsonToList(value:String) = Json.decodeFromString<Wow>(value)
}
@Database(entities = [User::class], version = 1)
@TypeConverters(TypeConverterWOW::class)
abstract class AppDatabase : RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun userDao(): UserDao
    companion object{
        //singleton prevents multiple instance of database opened at the same time
        @Volatile
        private var INSTANCE : AppDatabase? = null
        fun getDataBase(context: Context): AppDatabase{
            val tempInstance = INSTANCE
            if(tempInstance != null) return tempInstance
            synchronized(this){
                val instance = Room.databaseBuilder(context.applicationContext, AppDatabase::class.java, "database-name").build()
                INSTANCE = instance
                return instance
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I dont understand why this is happening but I've a bigger project that needs this to works,so please any help is apprecited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using converters with GSON library without an issue, try it if that helps:

```
// Add this dependency to build.gradle(:app)
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.8.1'
```

```
    @TypeConverter
    fun fromWoW(wow: WoW): String {
        return Gson().toJson(wow)
    }

    @TypeConverter
    fun toWoW(wowString: String): WoW {
        return Gson().fromJson(wowString, object : TypeToken<WoW>() {}.type)
    }
```

Comment: You're a life saver but if I've a data class with nested data class / lists of data classes would i need to write a converter for each or would Json handle it automatically

Comment: Yes, you should have two for each like WoW class. Because room can not know how to convert your data class to string or vice versa unless you tell it with typeConverters.